# JavaFX Refresh button disappears after 1 click

Tags: java, user-interface, button, javafx

I have a program in which it displays 3 random hieroglyphic images on the screen. I have added a "Refresh" button in order to refresh the hieroglyphic images. When I click the button, the images refresh and randomize properly. After the button has been clicked for the first time however, it disappears. I am almost certain it has something to do with my `pane.getChildren().clear();` line, but I cant seem to figure it out. Any tips or advice?

If I have posted incorrectly or without using proper guidelines, I apologize. This is one of my first posts.

Here is my code:

```
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.geometry.Pos;
    import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;

    public class Lab6a extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage myStage) {

    //Create an HBox layout.
    HBox hBox1 = new HBox();

    //Set alignment.
    hBox1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    getRandomHieroglyphic(hBox1);

    //Create a Refresh button.
    Button refresh = new Button("Refresh");
    refresh.setOnAction(e -> getRandomHieroglyphic(hBox1));
    hBox1.getChildren().add(refresh);

    //Set the title for the second window.
    myStage.setTitle("Random Hieroglyphics with Refresh");

    //Create a scene for the window.
    Scene myScene = new Scene(hBox1, 400, 400);

    //Place the scene in the second window.
    myStage.setScene(myScene);

    //Show the stage.
    myStage.show();
}

public void getRandomHieroglyphic(HBox pane) {
    pane.getChildren().clear();

    //Create random generators to get a random image
    int randomInt1 = (int) (Math.random() * 9) + 1;
    int randomInt2 = (int) (Math.random() * 9) + 1;
    int randomInt3 = (int) (Math.random() * 9) + 1;

    //Create paths for the images to be called
    String path1 = "Image/Hieroglyphics/h" + randomInt1 + ".png";
    String path2 = "Image/Hieroglyphics/h" + randomInt2 + ".png";
    String path3 = "Image/Hieroglyphics/h" + randomInt3 + ".png";

    //Add the images into the pane
    pane.getChildren().add(new ImageView (path1));
    pane.getChildren().add(new ImageView (path2));
    pane.getChildren().add(new ImageView (path3));        
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
 }  
}
```

Comment: You're right. You Hbox has 4 cildren initially, 3 images and the button. you should add the button too in the `getRandomHieroglyphic()` method.

Comment: But the better way was separate the button from the images. Best is this done by Adding a `BorderPane` to the Scene, and put the `HBox` with the images only in the `center` and the button in the `bottom` area.

Answer (score 1):

`clear()` removes all children from the `HBox` including the `Button`.

You've got 3 `ImageView`s and want to keep the number of `ImageView`s constant. This means you should not replace them, but replace the `image`s they contain instead. Furthermore you should avoid reloading the images and load all 9 images at the start:

```
public class Lab6a extends Application {

    private Image[] images;
    private final Random random = new Random();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage myStage) {
        // load all hieroglyphs
        images = new Image[9];
        for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            images[i] = new Image("Image/Hieroglyphics/h" + (i+1) + ".png");
        }

        // store all imageviews in array
        final ImageView[] imageViews = Stream.generate(ImageView::new).limit(3).toArray(ImageView[]::new);

        // set initial images
        getRandomHieroglyphic(imageViews);

        ...

        hBox1.getChildren().add(refresh);
        for (ImageView iv : imageViews) {
            hBox1.getChildren().add(iv);
        }
        ...
        refresh.setOnAction(e -> getRandomHieroglyphic(imageViews));
        ...
    }

    public void getRandomHieroglyphic(ImageView[] imageViews) {
        for (ImageView iv : imageViews) {
            iv.setImage(images[random.nextInt(images.length)]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Giving basically the same answer instead of editing the existing is a better idea?

Comment: This answer is vastly different than yours @TimothyTruckle.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. You Hbox has 4 cildren initially, 3 images and the button. you should add the button too in the getRandomHieroglyphic() method.

But the better way was separate the button from the images. Best is this done by Adding a BorderPane to the Scene, and put the HBox with the images only in the center and the button in the bottom area.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage myStage) {
   HBox hBox1 = new HBox();
   hBox1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
   getRandomHieroglyphic(hBox1);

   Button refresh = new Button("Refresh");
   refresh.setOnAction(e -> getRandomHieroglyphic(hBox1));
   BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
   borderPane.getBottom().add(refresh);

   myStage.setTitle("Random Hieroglyphics with Refresh");
   Scene myScene = new Scene(borderPane, 400, 400);
```